# Identifying replacement freehub

Tags: freehub

I’ve been tasked to source a replacement freehub, any ideas what this type would be? Might be obvious forgive my ignorance!

Forgot to mention, it’s from a Marin bike. That’s all I know so far

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you knew which hub the freehub belongs to.

Comment: The cassette interface is Shimano/SRAM. The make of the hub itself is the relevant factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to be the standard Shimano RM30/RM33 variant.  The freehubs are different for 7speed vs the 8/9/10speed versions, so double check the speeds before replacement.

Answer (score 0):

So far I’m seeing results for Shimano FH-TX800, FH-RM30, FH-RM33, FH-RM60, FH-RM65 variants.

Will have to research further and also ask how many gears on the bike but appreciate any more ideas anyone might have